# How to print the name of a Python object in a single line?

Tags: python

I am trying to print the name of an object

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.svm import SVC

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None, 'display.width', 2500)

est = SVC(kernel='poly')
print(est)
```

The output is:

```
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto_deprecated',
  kernel='poly', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

I would like to print this output in just 1 line (not 4).
Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Do you have a really *really* wide monitor?

Comment: It depends what terminal emulator you're using and what its line wrap options are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) function :

```
def print_line(obj)
    print( str(obj).replace('\n','') )
```